# assets:precompile doesn't seem to work, locally or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

When pushing a Rails 3.2.11 app to heroku, running `rake assets:precompile` or `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` doesn't seem to make assets available - it doesn't matter if I run this rake task locally or not.

The only solution is to set `config.assets.compile = true` in `production.rb` which seems to make the app super slow in production.

I haven't had this issue with other applications.

How do I diagnose what the deal is?

Answer (score 0):

When you run this task locally, make sure that you've commited newly created files.